# Gravity forms multiple posts generated by one form

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-gravity-forms

**THE GOAL**

*Example 1: Job Applicant + Mailing List*

Wondering if this could be possible, I have a simple form of 30 fields of Curricullum Vitae of some Job Applicant (custom post type: job_applicant) and I would like to use let's say 5 fields from this form to automaticaly create a new user for custom post type ("mailing_list")

*Example 2: Event + Club listings*

Another example is to generate the form using custom post type "EVENT" with club location fields and then after submission in the background create a new custom post type "club_listings" info.
Is it hard to create in the background e new custom post type CLUB entry with some 3-5 fields one per line?

**Purpose**

1. Time saving
2. Better categorizing

**Conclusion**

Can somebody help me by providing any example here ?
All I want is to use one form to generate 2 different custom post type posts.
I am able to create the one bigger form, I would like to know if there's some simple hack to generate also another one different little CPT form with 3-5 specific fields.
I am trying to understand this issue with the help of documentation on GF pages:
http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission

Very amateur example below:

```
01  <?php
02  add_action("gform_after_submission", "set_post_content", 10, 2);
03  function set_post_content($entry, $form){
04   
05      //creating NEW custom post type entry
06      $post = 
07   
08      //creating custom post type content
09      $post->post_content = "Club Info: "<br/> " . $entry[1] . " <br/>
10   "<br/> " . $entry[2] . " <br/>
11   "<br/> " . $entry[3] . " <br/>
12   "<br/> " . $entry[4] . " <br/>
13   "<br/> " . $entry[5] . " <br/>
14   
15      //updating post
16      wp_update_post($post);
17  }
18  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the example link you mentioned, it assumes you are using the post generation features that are built into Gravity Forms. I imagine you'll want to bypass that if you are trying to create more than one post object per form submission. In the `gform_after_submission` hook, I'd do something a bit like this...

```
// add the new post EVENT
$event_post_args = array(
    'comment_status' => 'closed', // or open
    'ping_status' => 'closed',
    'post_author' => 1, // this represents admin by default.
                        // might need to pull user info if is real user

    'post_title' => $entry[1] . ' - ' . $entry[2], // note i have no clue
                                                   // what you want here
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'post_type' => 'event',                                 
);

// this returns an integer on success, 0 on failure - creates post!
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $event_post_args );

// add more meta values if you need
$event_meta_values = array(
    'event_address'     => $entry[3],
    'event_phone'       => $entry[4],
    'event_something'   => $entry[5],
);

// as long as wp_insert_post didnt fail...
if($post_id > 0){
    foreach($event_meta_values as $key => $value) {
        // add our post meta
        update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
    }
}

// now we just do the same kind of thing for other Post Type
$club_post_args = array(
    ...
    ...
    'post_title' => $entry[6],
);

// etc.
```

Bear in mind all of that goes in your `gform_after_submission` hook, which should probably be specifically built for one particular form. You can add an underscore and the ID of the form on the hook to accomplish that: `gform_after_submission_7`, for example.

You might also want some conditionals in this code to make sure those values aren't empty before trying to make a post or post meta out of them.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: @GhoastToast you are my personal responder :), I will examine all this code tonight and will immediately tell you how it works, thanks a lot for your quick answer!